# I need to replace the spring-loaded lighting cover for the light in the tub

Tags: electrical, light-fixture, bathroom-fixtures

Anyone know where I can get a trim kit for this basic round ceiling light?

It has an outer edge/flange that seats against the ceiling and there is a plastic light cover inside the outer edge. It has a rubber gasket that fits against the opening of the light and it has the 2 spring loaded tension wires that get squeezed together to remove and replace the entire fixture.

The part of the wire clip that is bent around the plastic inner seal broke off and the rubber gasket is deteriorated. I dont need the fixture inside the ceiling where the bulb is. I just need the entire one piece outer covering - about 6 inches wide.

Answer (score 1):

Trim kits for "can lights" (recessed lights) are sold separately.

The box stores have them or you can find them online. Like this one [here](http://www.lampsplus.com/products/juno-6-inch-line-voltage-wet-location-recessed-light-trim__02494.html).

For a shower/tub enclosure you need a trim kit rated for wet locations. It will have the gasket and springs like the old one.

Take the old one to the store with you to make sure you get the right size. They come in 4, 5, and 6" sizes. Or measure the "can" part of the fixture if you wish to buy online.

Good luck!